# Please help me to write 2 words in one single lane

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, text

I want to write to words in one lane but there are different things so i tried many time the only way that helped me is writing with `&nbsp;` but it is not working correctly because when you change the sizes of website it is not working in the same way correct as then so here is the code

```
<div class="card-body">
            <span class="bold lot-date">2011</span>
            <p class="price-right"><span class="close">$10000</span></p>
            <h8 class="card-text">RESTYLING</h8>
          </div>




   .price-right {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 268px;
  margin-left: 116px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #369;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.close {
  font-size: 18px;

  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: What is a "lane"?  Do you mean columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this css

```
.card-body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

You are putting the flex on the wrong element. You want it on the div that holds the elements, not the elements themselves.

Comment: Yeah it helped some how but there is appearing another problem lol here is the whole code that i have on this one